# How can I remove Block Programatically from layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, controllers, layout-update

I want to remove the block.

so

How can I remove Block Programmatically from layout?

Comment: How is this unclear?? Both question and answer super clear to me.. if you've been doing magento for a few years at least then there is no unclarity here..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
 $this->getLayout()->unsetBlock('your_block_name');
```

Things that you need to ensure here is,

1. The block with specified name should exist in the layout !
2. This should perform after `$this->loadLayout()` and before `$this->renderLayout()`.

***Why ?*** Because `$this->loadLayout()` that comes inside controller is what actually loads all blocks which is related to the page that is going to show in frontend. So if you perform the operation before loading layout, it wont work, because there is no related layout exist. Similarly if you perform the operation after `$this->renderLayout()`, then that become too late ! Because Magento already rendered output in frontend.